# Operator comma overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

I'm trying to learn more about how operator overloading works.

I understand that overloading the comma operator may not be the best idea, but this is for instructional purposes only.

I'm expecting the following code to use my overloaded operator (I used brackets as I'm aware the comma operator has the lowest precedence) to construct a vector containing (1,2) and then call the vector's assignment operator.

However, I get an error:

```
no known conversion from argument 1 from 'int' to 'const std::vector<int>&'
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  (1,2) should construct a vector so it shouldn't be trying to convert from an `int` to a `vector<int>`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using std::vector;
using std::move;

template <typename T>
vector<T> operator,(const T& v1, const T& v2)
{
    vector<T> v;
    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);
    return move(v);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    a = (1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*so it shouldnt' be trying to convert from an int to a vector?*" -- That's precisely what it tries to do, but since there's no `vector` constructor that only takes in `int`, it doesn't know how to, and that's exactly the error message you're getting, no?

Comment: Certainly it isn't.  He didn't copy the part of the message that says that it is related to the failed attempt to match a valid assignment operator (`operator=`) function to the object `a`.

Comment: @Dolda2000: "*there's no vector constructor that only takes in int*" - no, but there is one that accepts a `vector::size_type` instead (to specify the initial number of default-constructed items to fill the vector with), and an `int` can be assigned to a `vector::size_type`. However, a `vector` cannot be *implicitly* constructed from an `int`/`size_type`, only *explicitly*, which is why an `int` cannot be passed to `vector::operator=` directly.

Comment: Overloading of the comma operator is not recommend, per the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading) also check out [More Effective C++, Item 7](http://debian.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/~mrpaff/Effective%20C++/MEC/MI7_FR.HTM)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sure, but that constructor is `explicit`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is already a built-in definition for the comma operator applied to ints. Your template isn't even in the running for overload resolution, since you can't overload operators unless at least one of the arguments is a user defined type.

You could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct vector_maker
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vector_maker& operator,(T const& rhs) {
        vec.push_back(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<T> finalize() {
        return std::move(vec);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto a = (vector_maker<int>(),1,2,3,4,5).finalize();
}
```

Or take a look at [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), which allows constructions like this:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression on the right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated simply as `(1,2)` and degenerates to `(2)` or `2`, which is an `int`.

Then the assignment is evaluated. The left-hand side is of type `vector<int>`. You are attempting to assign `2` (an `int`) to `a` (a `vector<int>`), and since there is no conversion from an `int` to a `vector<>` you get the error.

You won't be able to overload the operators for built-in types, such as `int`.